# "very pleased to read your posting" -- pleased=happy vs. pleased=satisfied

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, politeness

In a formal context, I would like to tell the author (whom I admire) of a posting that I was happy that I discovered/found it because I did not expect it.

> I was very pleased to read your posting in last week's issue of ...

I am concerned that *pleased* might come across as *satisfied*, like I am his boss telling him that he did a good job.

I have also thought about

> I was very pleased to *have found* your posting in last week's issue of ...

Any comment would be appreciated. (I am not a native speaker.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Pleased* can be used to express enjoyment; "pleased to read" can also mean "glad to read".

You could also write one of the following sentences.

> I was glad to read your post on the last week issue's […].
>   I enjoyed reading your post […].
>   I was glad to find your post […].

Comment: What does "I was glad to read your post on the last week issue's" mean?

Answer (score 1):

This one contains all your sentiments:

I was pleasantly surprised to find your posting...

Answer (score 0):

I think both of your examples would have the effect you are looking for.   The second is the better of the two in my opinion though; it conveys a little more context.